# php cookies only working on localhost

Tags: php, cookies, localhost

I recently started doing some php and made this code for language change with a cookie. It works totaly fine on localhost but when I upload it, the browser seems to not save any cookie.

So i tried setting the domain for both localhost and server, but it still does not work.

```
$whitelist = array(
    '127.0.0.1', 
    '::1'
);
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)){
    $domain = '.localhost';
} else {
    $domain = '.bjarnesc.de';
}
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    setcookie('lang', $lang, (time()+(86400*30)), "/", $domain);
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $lang;
}
else if (!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    setcookie('lang', 'de', (time()+(86400*30)), "/", $domain);
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = 'de';
}
if ($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'en') {
    include("../languages/en.php");
}   else if ($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'de') {
    include("../languages/de.php");
}
```

Comment: Why there's a dot '.' before the domain name `.bjarnesc.de`?

Comment: @Karkouch its a requirement of the specs, but ignored mostly by browsers who do all the work

Comment: Just guessing here, but maybe you have PHP configured to automatically start sessions locally and it is not the case on you prod environment?

Comment: Even though I looked through lots and lots of post, I only now found a clear explanation, that the cookie has to be always set at the very beginning of the file, so now it works. Thanks for the answer anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Most propably the issue is - Headers are already sent due to whitespace in your included files or in the same file itself. Either fix that or set cookie at beginning.